# generic methods with observablecollections

Tags: c#, generics, windows-runtime, .net-4.5

This is for a Windows 8.1 Store app using .Net 4.5

**I found myself replicating the same code for each "object" that I have.**  So I'm trying to create a more generic method to get all the data the way I want.  Originally everything was `<Typed>` to my different objects but now I'm trying to use the generic `<Object>`.

```
    public async Task<ObservableCollection<object>>selectAll()
    {
        var Items = await Win8StorageHelper.LoadData("person.dat", typeof(ObservableCollection<object>));
        ObservableCollection<object> ItemsList = new ObservableCollection<object>();
        if (typeof(Int32) == Items.GetType())
        {
            //Not Needed anymore
        }
        else
        {
            ItemsList = (ObservableCollection<object>)Items;
        }
        _list.Clear();
        foreach (object item in ItemsList)
        {
            _list.Add(item);
        }

        return _list;
    }
```

I have my original collection _frequencyList and now a new generic collection _list:

```
    private ObservableCollection<win8Chores.Model.databaseTables.Frequency> _frequencyList;
    public ObservableCollection<Object> _list = new ObservableCollection<Object>();
```

I'm trying to call my new method like this:

```
_frequencyList = await selectAll();
```

However, I'm getting an error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection' to
>   'System.Collections.ObjectModel>observableCollection'

What do I need to do to get this code to work?  Am I even on the right track?  Any help is appreciated.

**Update:**
These are the original methods I was trying to refactor for the generic example:

```
    public async Task<ObservableCollection<Person>> selectAllPersons()
    {
        var personItems = await Win8StorageHelper.LoadData("person.dat", typeof(ObservableCollection<Person>));
        ObservableCollection<Person> personItemsList = new ObservableCollection<Person>();
        if (typeof(Int32) == personItems.GetType())
        {
            //Not Needed anymore
        }
        else
        {
            personItemsList = (ObservableCollection<Person>)personItems;
        }
        _personList.Clear();
        foreach (Person item in personItemsList)
        {
            _personList.Add(item);
        }

        return _personList;
    }

    public async Task<ObservableCollection<Frequency>> selectAllFrequencies()
    {
        var frequencyItems = await Win8StorageHelper.LoadData("frequency.dat", typeof(ObservableCollection<Frequency>));
        ObservableCollection<Frequency> frequencyItemsList = new ObservableCollection<Frequency>();
        if (typeof(Int32) == frequencyItems.GetType())
        {
            //Not Needed anymore
        }
        else
        {
            frequencyItemsList = (ObservableCollection<Frequency>)frequencyItems;
        }
        _frequencyList.Clear();
        foreach (Frequency item in frequencyItemsList)
        {
            _frequencyList.Add(item);
        }
        return _frequencyList;
    }
    public async Task<ObservableCollection<Chore>> selectAllChores()
    {
        var choreItems = await Win8StorageHelper.LoadData("chore.dat", typeof(ObservableCollection<Chore>));
        ObservableCollection<Chore> choreItemsList = new ObservableCollection<Chore>();
        if (typeof(Int32) == choreItems.GetType())
        {
            //Not Needed anymore
        }
        else
        {
            choreItemsList = (ObservableCollection<Chore>)choreItems;
        }
        _choreList.Clear();
        foreach (Chore item in choreItemsList)
        {
            _choreList.Add(item);
        }
        return _choreList;
    }
```

Comment: *Why* are you using `object` instead of your specific types now?

Comment: I was re-writing this same method for each type.  I figured that it could be refactored so I don't have to re-write the same method over and over again.  Is that not the right way to go?

Comment: Sounds like a case for generics. That allows you to retain the types and still be flexible.

Comment: Is the <object> not generic?  How would I convert my code above to be "Generic"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need something like this

```
public async Task<ObservableCollection<T>> selectAllItems<T>(ObservableCollection<T> _list)
{
    var items = await Win8StorageHelper.LoadData(string.Format("{0}.dat",typeof(T).Name.ToLower()), typeof(ObservableCollection<T>));

    _list.Clear();
    if(!(items is ObservableCollection<T>))
    {
         return _list;
    }

    ObservableCollection<T> itemsList = (ObservableCollection<T>)items;        
    foreach (T item in itemsList)
    {
        _list.Add(item);
    }

    return _list;
}
```

`_list` is the parameter where you need to add all the items.

Then call it like

```
selectAllItems(_personList);
selectAllItems(_frequencyList); //etc
```

Comment: Sakthievel - I keep getting errors on the "T": Namespace name "T" cannot be found... What am I missing here?

Comment: Updated code, method signature to be like this `public async Task<ObservableCollection<T>> selectAllItems<T>(ObservableCollection<T> _list)`

Comment: I'll have to try this tonight.  Do you know if there are any differences with doing Generics with .Net 4.5 in a Windows Store app?

Comment: I don't think there will be a difference since both are properties of .net framework not the platform you use

Comment: yeah that is what I was thinking too, but that isn't what I was seeing in my error list.  I created a test class on a separate project and the code looked fine.  Not sure what is going on with my project at home...  I'll let you know.

Comment: This finally worked on my machine.  Thank you for this.  I understand all the <T> except the selectAllItems<T> what does this <T> represent?

Comment: <T> represents you are going to use a generic type inside the method. It can be anything <X>, <Y> etc. <T1,T2> means you're going to use two generic types inside the method. Learn more about [generics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379564%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

I think you should be using generics for this; see [Introduction to C# Generics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379564%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

```
public async Task<ObservableCollection<T1>> selectAll<T1>(string filename)
{
    var Items = await Win8StorageHelper.LoadData(filename, typeof(ObservableCollection<T1>));

    if (Items is ObservableCollection<T1>)
    {
         return ((ObservableCollection<T1>)Items).ToList();
    }
    else
    {
        // empty or not the right type; depending on what the storage helper gives us
        return new ObservableCollection<T1>();
    }
}
```

called by

```
var personList = selectAll<Person>("person.dat");
var frequencyList = selectAll<Person>("frequency.dat");
```

Comment: I'm looking at that as well and I'm getting an error that says Type or Namespace 'T' is not found.  Are you missing a reference or assembly.  I checked and I do have using System.Collections.Generic;

Comment: it should work if you do Task<ObservableCollection<YourType>>; or refer to it via a class type or method parameter type;

possibly post a larger runnable sample (LINQpad is good for this) and we'll be able to help better

Comment: if I have 3 objects that will all use this function is that the same as rewriting 3 times? - See my updated question

Comment: one method should be enough; see revised answer.

Comment: When ever I try to implement this in my code I keep getting errors on the "T": Namespace name "T" cannot be found...  What am I missing?  Does the class that contains this method need to be generic<T>?